# :gt(0) vs :not(:first) vs .slice(1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Before this I've always used [`gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to select all elements except first. Now I found solution that seems more elegant to me. It's to use `:not(:first)` instead of `:gt(0)`.
Is there any differences in performance of this selectors and which one do you suggest to use?

**EDIT:** As mentioned Felix King, `.slice(1)` is another option to select all elements except first. So which is faster?

Comment: You can also try `.slice(1)` instead of a custom selector.

Comment: They are both slow, method suggested by @FelixKling should be the fastest one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Time for a bit of profiling! Given a page that’s empty apart from ten `<span>`s cached into a variable called `spans` and 10,000 iterations I get 824ms for `spans.filter(':gt(0)')` and 1276ms for `spans.not(':first')`.

Figure achieved using `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` in Firefox 11.

Considering I had to do 10k iterations to hit the 1sec mark I’d suggest it doesn’t matter?

Comment: Would you care to add into that a comparison of @Felix Kling's slice method which some commenters suggest is better?

Comment: Sure! Using the `slice(1)` method the same test comes out as 79ms - about 10 times faster than `:gt(0)`

Comment: I thought that :not:first would work faster, thanks for testing. And +1 for slice(1) comparison too.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing. I'll keep this in mind for later.

Answer (score 3):

Wrote a jsperf test for this:

http://jsperf.com/select-all-but-first-42

Turns out the slice method is fastest!

There's another test on jsperf for the same requirement:

http://jsperf.com/select-all-but-first